# How to increase space between bibliography without using biblatex

Tags: spacing, bibliographies

Is there a way to increase space between bibliography without using `biblatex`?

Comment: I don't understand. Would you mind explaining a bit more?

Answer (score 6):

If you mean the space between the various references (`\bibitem`s) this can be done as follows using `etoolbox` to patch the `\thebibliography` command.

In normal styles the bibliography is just a list, but the parameters of the list are given when the bibliography is called (`\begin{bibliography}` which calls `\thebibliography`).

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\apptocmd{\thebibliography}{\setlength{\itemsep}{18pt}}{}{}
```

The same idea can be used for other parameters of the list implementing the bibliography.

An alternative is to use `natbib` which provides `\bibsep` (`\setlength{\bibsep}{18pt}`) to change the vertical space between references.

```
\usepackage{natbib}
\setlength{\bibsep}{18pt}
```

PS replace `18pt` with the measure you want.