# How can I reduce the line spacing in references?

Tags: spacing, cross-referencing

I am trying to reduce the spacing in between the references to save some space. However, I couldn't do it by myself. I am using the `article` class, and a portion of my code is as follows:

```
\documentclass[9pt]{extarticle}
\providecommand{\keywords}[1]{\textbf{\textit{Index Terms---}} #1}
\usepackage{spconf,amsmath,graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}


\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tabularx,colortbl}
\usepackage{amssymb} % \in
\usepackage{amsmath} % For align command
\usepackage[breaklinks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{subfigure}

\begin{document}
Huuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu!!

\bibliographystyle{IEEEbib}
\bibliography{references}

\end{document}
```

How can I manage to reduce the line spacing in reference section?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess you need to apply some spacing preference before `\bibliography`. Try something like `\singlespacing`.

Comment: Substitute the line `\bibliography{references}` with `{\linespread{0.7}\selectfont\bibliography{biblio}}` and adjust `0.7` to your needs.

Comment: The second command worked, but it reduced the line spacing in all of the lines. Actually, I need to reduce the space between each reference.

Comment: See this thread: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/98554/27635. I think this is a duplicate.

Comment: You could load the `etoolbox` package and issue the following command (in the preamble): `\AtBeginEnvironment{thebibliography}{\setlength\parskip{0pt}}`. This makes this parameter a rigid length rather than a "rubber" length (its default setting).