# Linebreaks after bib items for Bibstyle (using BibLaTeX)

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, pdftex, line-breaking

I am currently suffering of a strange bibstyle problem with line breaks.
There is a missing space between bib items in the bibliography, which is generated using BibLaTeX.

[image]

Even though I am using the authoryear bibstyle, I do not get the line breaks after each bib item.

```
\usepackage[citestyle=authoryear,bibstyle=authoryear,url=false,doi=true,natbib=true,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\renewcommand{\nameyeardelim}{ }%
\renewcommand{\multicitedelim}{, }%
\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{andothers={et\addabbrvspace al\adddot}}


\renewcommand{\cite}{\citep}%
\addbibresource{/home/robert/Documents/franzi/diss/Literatur/library.bib}
```

Is there any possibility to adjust the space after each bib item with a dedicated biblatex parameter? I have searched through the manual but was not finding something useful.

Comment: Sorry, I may be mistaken but I think that this is the expected output for `bibstyle=authoryear`.  I'm not sure I understand what you were expecting.  Did you want some extra **vertical** space between bibitems?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to increase space between bibliography without using biblatex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98554/how-to-increase-space-between-bibliography-without-using-biblatex)

Comment: Look at the commands `\bibitemsep`, `\bibnamesep`, and `\bibinitsep`: the first sets the space between *all* items; the second sets the space between different *names* (e.g., no space between items by the same author, only between different authors); and the third sets the space between different *letters* (e.g., space between the last B-name and first C-name).  These are all set using `\setlength`; e.g.: `\setlength{\bibnameset}{\baselineskip}`.

Comment: @Jon You should turn that in to answer.

Comment: @jon: Your comment about \bibitemsep was helping here! Can you provide this as an answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`biblatex` gives the user fine-grained control over how vertical spacing is used in the bibliography.  Three commands are relevant:

- `\bibitemsep`: this sets the space between individual entries;
- `\bibnamesep`: this sets the space between entries belonging to different (groups of) individuals --- say, the space between "Smith, John" and "Smythe, Paul", but not between the different entries for the same (groups of) author(s).
- `\bibinitsep`: this sets the space between the groups of entries that begin with a different letter --- say the space between all the S-names (Smith, Smythe, etc.) and T-names (Thompson, Thomas, etc.)

All these commands are set using `\setlength`; e.g.,

```
\setlength{\bibnamesep}{\baselineskip}
```

Note also that they are designed in such a way that if more than one of these commands are set to a non-zero amount, only the largest of them will be applied.

Related to these commands are the following:

- `\bibhang`: this sets the value for the hanging indent in the bibliography (if applicable); it is initially set equal to `\parindent`;
- `\biblabelsep`: this command, meant for `numeric` and `alphabetic` styles, controls the horizontal space between the individual entries and their corresponding labels; it is initially set to twice the value of `\labelsep`; and
- `\bibparsep`: this sets the vertical space between paragraphs *within an entry* in the bibliography; it is initially set to 0.

These are all discussed in "§ 3.9.3 Lengths and Counters" of the `biblatex` manual (v. 2.7a).